# JQuery change input type hidden value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I changing input type hidden over JQuery with DOM appended Buttons, code looks like

```
$("body").on('click', '.companyContractButt', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var what = $(this).attr('data-what');
    alert($(".selectedWhatis[data-id='"+id+"']").attr('data-id'));
    $(".selectedWhatis[data-id='"+id+"']").val(what);
    alert($(".selectedWhatis[data-id='"+id+"']").val());
});
```

and input type hidden looks

```
<input type='hidden' data-id='".$contract->id."' class='selectedWhatis' value='hovno'>
```

But wher I alert that input type hidden I always get undefined... I don't know why. var id and var what showing right values..

There is function which creating DOM buttons

```
$("body").on('click', '.clickChange', function(){
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
var nm = $(this).attr('data-name');

$(".filling[data-id='"+id+"']").html('');
$(".filling[data-id='"+id+"']").html("<button class='companyContractButt' data-what='create' data-id='"+id+"'><span>"+$("#createTranslate").val()+"</span></button> <button class='companyContractButt' data-what='append' data-id='"+id+"'><span>"+$("#appendTranslate").val()+"</span></button><br /><input type='text' style='width: 200px; margin-top: 5px;' data-id='"+id+"' value='"+nm+"' class='inputingPerson'>");
$(".inputingPerson[data-id='"+id+"']").focus();
});
```

Comment: can you try with `alert($("input[class=selectedWhatis][data-id='"+id+"']").val());`

Comment: Still undefined :-/, but everythink have right values, just show me undefined, I don't understand this error....

Comment: `alert($('.selectedWhatis[data-id='+id+']').val());` pls try

Comment: pekka solution, work for me : https://jsfiddle.net/syyn5jdx/

Comment: please show us `.companyContractButt` button's html code

Comment: Does this `alert($(".selectedWhatis[data-id='"+id+"']").attr('data-id'));` correctly alerts  `data-id` of the hidden input?

Comment: i believe your button's `data-id` and `hidden` field's `data-id` are not in sync.

Comment: What do you menay synchronizeted? It it in document ready func. and I calling event on click by DOM. So I don't understand what can't be sync.

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2wxfL559/)

```
var id = 5

$('.selectedWhatis').attr('data-id', id);


alert($('.selectedWhatis[data-id='+id+']').val())
```

Check this sample and try it out. I just use `''` for this

Comment: in the fiddle it alerts the id value? maybe something else is wrong?

Comment: No, I check every values and error is when I getting value of input type hidden, its looks like that JS don't see that element

Comment: it should as you can see in the fiddle it alert the value which is `hovno`

Comment: I edited post, added function for adding DOM buttons, maybe it will helps.

Comment: @user5366720: Does this `alert($(".selectedWhatis[data-id='"+id+"']").attr('data-id'));` correctly alerts data-id of the hidden input?